# Redirect to proxy location block in Nginx

Tags: nginx-config

I want to use same @proxy block if some conditions met. I don’t want to use multiples proxy pass as I don’t want to define proxy rules multiple times.

If can be ok to be outside of location block, if that’s allowed or better practice.

```
location / {
    if ($condition_true) {
    // jump to @proxy block
    // no proxy pass here
    }
    try_files $uri $uri/index.html @proxy;

}

location @proxy {

     // multiple proxy rules, headers, etc
    proxy_pass http://example.com;

}
```